# populating associations in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, associations

I'm new to mean and mongodb and was trying to figure out how to populate my answers to my questions. I just changed the words in the platform that I'm learning (examples were posts and comments).

Here's the error message I'm getting.

```
/Users/joerigby/Documents/codingdojo/full mean/blacktest3/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:62
throw new Error('No default engine was specified and no extension was prov
      ^
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
at new View (/Users/joerigby/Documents/codingdojo/full mean/blacktest3/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:62:11)
at EventEmitter.render (/Users/joerigby/Documents/codingdojo/full mean/blacktest3/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:569:12)
at ServerResponse.render (/Users/joerigby/Documents/codingdojo/full mean/blacktest3/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
at /Users/joerigby/Documents/codingdojo/full mean/blacktest3/server/controllers/answers_c.js:53:12
at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/joerigby/Documents/codingdojo/full mean/blacktest3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2112:28)
at /Users/joerigby/Documents/codingdojo/full mean/blacktest3/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
at /Users/joerigby/Documents/codingdojo/full mean/blacktest3/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
24 Aug 16:48:22 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Below are my codes..

from answers_controller.js on server side

```
    show: function(req, res){
        console.log(req.params.id);

        Question.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
                .populate('answers')
          .exec(function(err, question) {
            res.render('question', {question: question});
                });
            }
    }
```

from answer model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var AnswerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    answer: String,
    description: String,
    likes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
    _question: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}
});
mongoose.model('Answer', AnswerSchema);
```

from question model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;


var QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
  answers: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer'}]
});
mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

Let me know if you need anything else to look at.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: That error message is referring to your view rendering engine, so it likely has nothing to do with MongoDB or population.  A search on that error message gets lots of SO hits.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not with Mongo or Mongoose. Check the stack trace in your error message. The problem is from `res.render`. In order to use this method you must either configure express to have a default view engine (ejs, jade, etc.) or provide a file extension after 'question' so that it knows which template file to look for in order to render the HTML.

```
// in your main server file

// set default view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// set view folder (where it looks for the template files
app.set('views', pathToViewFolder);
```

Now you can create a `question.ejs` file in the folder at `pathToViewFolder`.